# Android Studio getSupportFragment.beginTransaction().replace causing crashes when navigating to another fragment(Java)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to implement a side-navigation bar (hamburger menu). I want to be able to select a new fragment to view from this menu, and then click buttons on that fragment to direct to another fragment (not in the hamburger menu list).

I was following a guide (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bjYstsO1PgI), but it doesn't show the second step of redirecting to the other fragment.

I keep getting a crash whenever I click a button that redirects to the other fragment, if it has been loaded by the hamburger menu.

The line I use is to render from the hamburger menu is:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new FirstFragment()).commit();
```

This is called by the following event listener:

```
 NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
 navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

and I get this error whenever I press a button to go to the 'other' fragment.

```
Navigation action/destination com.example.testApp:id/action_FirstFragment_to_submitScreen cannot be found from the current destination Destination(com.example.testApp:id/submitScreen) label=fragment_submit_screen class=com.example.renamedTestApp.SubmitScreen
```

This error is not present when I use

```
<include layout="@layout/content_main"/>
```

to load the first fragment on app startup (the one from the hamburger menu).

Any tips? This question may be confusing so let me know if I should tidy up my explanation.
I believe the error may be in the fragment not being fully loaded perhaps? If that is the case, what would be a better line to use to switch on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

provide some code

try this

```
FragmentManager fragmnt= getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction tr= fragmnt.beginTransaction();
tr.replace(R.id.YOUR,new Yourfragment());
//or tr.replace(R.id.content_frame, new Yourfragment());
tr.commit();
```

Comment: Im not quite sure I understand. Isn't that exactly the code I provided in my question, just spaced out to be on multiple lines?

Comment: Forgive me, but I am unsure which code you would like to see. I have included the event listener that calls the code I showed in my original post.

Comment: its seems fine ,try is https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-navigation-drawer-example-using-fragments/